# How are strings passed into methods in java (In terms of memory)

Tags: java, heap-memory, stack-memory

When we call methods, if you are passing in a primitive type, that value is put on the stack frame when calling the method. If you are passing in a reference type, if it's not null, you would have already created it on the heap some where and what gets put on the stack is a reference to it.

But what happens on the stack, when I do something like

```
person.setName("Jack");
```

Does it first create a string object on the heap and then put a reference to that on the stack?

Comment: A String is an Object. Its reference is passed as any other reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your code, `"Jack"` is a String *constant* so it resides in the [run-time constant pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.5). This pool resides in an area of the JVM called the method area.

However, if the code is changed to:

```
Person.SetName(new String("Jack"));
```

then the passed reference points to an object on the heap, as it would normally for any reference type.

Comment: Would new String("Jack")) create two objects? First for the literal "Jack" and second for New String() ?

Comment: @Foo Yes this is correct. The literal is created once for the class and shared.

Comment: This has to do with JVM optimizations. `"Jack"` is created as a constant. If any other line creates the same string `"Jack"` no new object will be constructed, it will get the same reference of constant constructed previously. However `new String("Jack")` will create a new String at runtime in heap using the constant.

Comment: @Foo Yes, but it doesn't create the two objects at the same time.  The first object, for the literal, is created early, and only once.  `new String("Jack")` creates a new `String` and copies the data from the constant object.  This happens every time `new String` is executed.  There really is no reason to ever use `new String(s)` where `s` is any other `String`, whether it's a constant or some other expression.